# If/else statements in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-native

I have a problem with if/else statements in React Native.

For example, I have two states:

```
onOpen() {
  this.setState({
    index: 1
  });
}

onClose() {
  this.setState({
    index: 0
  });
}
```

I need to set State index: 0, when toggle close and index: 1, when toggle open.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
  {index === 0 
    ? navigator.toggleDrawer(this.onClose()) 
    : navigator.toggleDrawer(this.onOpen())
  }
}>
```

For now, when I click on menu-button I receive index 0 every time, but they should change on 1 and back. Thanks.

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image 
} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0
    };
  }
  onOpen() {
    this.setState({
      index: 1
    });
  }

  onClose() {
    this.setState({
      index: 0
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { index } = this.state;
    return (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {index === 1 ? 
     navigator.toggleDrawer(this.onClose()) : 
     navigator.toggleDrawer(this.onOpen())}}>
        <Image
        source={require('something.png')}
       />    
   </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please include your entire render method, since it's not quite clear how you get the `index`.

Comment: shouldn't your `{index === 0}` should be `{this.state.index === 0}` ?

Comment: best guess is that your "this" variable isn't pointing to your scope. try this.onClose.bind(this)()

Comment: @Throlle I include component.

Comment: Why so complicated? Just name your function *onToggle* and negate your index.

Comment: @Robert onToggle it is native function from ex-navigation lib, I can't change it.

Comment: @ValeriaShpiner: You can name it whatever you want ;)

Comment: what is `navigator.toogleDrawer()` use for?

Comment: @HanaAlaydrus for open drawer menu

Comment: @ValeriaShpiner can you show us the code for `navigator.toogleDrawer()` ?

Comment: @HanaAlaydrus no, because it is inside ex-navigation lib.

Comment: look when I add bind(this) I have index: 0, when I click at the first time at logo and index: 1 when I click on the second time, but I need 0 when I call Toggle and 1 at the all remaining time.

Answer (score 2):

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { index: 0 };
    this.toggleIndex = this.toggleIndex.bind(this);
  }

  toggleIndex() {
    navigator.toggleDrawer();
    this.setState({ index: this.state.index === 0 ? 1 : 0 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleIndex}>
        <Image
          source={require('something.png')}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it works, but problem is still here:
when I click on logo at the first time I call toggleDrawer and have index 1, and when I click at the second time I have index 0, but I heed to have index 0 every time when toggleDrawer is not active.

Comment: initially `this.state.index` is 0 and your drawer is **not active**. Now you click on logo, and `this.state.index` becomes 1. This also invokes `navigator.toggleDrawer()` so I presume that will set your drawer **active**. Again if you press, `this.state.index` becomes 0 and `navigator.toggleDrawer()` will make your drawer back to **not active**. I cannot see your trouble here. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I added image with example. When I click at the first time, toggleDrawer is called, menu open and index becomes 1, BUT when it closes I still have index 1, and I need to press again if I would like to receive index 0, but I wouldn't press again. I need to have index 0, when toggleDrawer is not call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that when you close the drawer you don't really press the menu button, but the dark overlay, thus your onPress function is not called. Try to find if there is any event when the drawer is open / closed and set the state in that event instead.

Comment: It is the main problem, because this dark overlay somewhere inside lib and I can't find this connection =(

Comment: @ValeriaShpiner, https://github.com/expo/ex-navigation this is the library?

Comment: @ValeriaShpiner, It seems that the library does not provide a way to be notified when the drawer is open / closed. I've added 2 new props in DrawerNavigation: `onDrawerClose` and `onDrawerOpen`. Can you try it? If it works I'll submit a pull request for it.
1) Replace in package.json `"@expo/ex-navigation": "^3.0.0"`,
with
`"@expo/ex-navigation": "git+https://github.com/mlazari/ex-navigation.git#add-close-open-events"`,
2) run `npm install`
3) `<DrawerNavigation onDrawerClose={() => alert('Closed')} onDrawerOpen={() => alert('Open')} ...`